# How to get the email address of user who paste code in our website using GoogleAuthenticator?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to install the GoogleAuthenticator script , code verification is doing perfect . But i want to know that how i will get the username(emailaddress) of the user by GoogleAuthenticator .
Please Guide me ,Thanks in advance

Language **PHP**

I am using below code for verification.

```
$checkResult = $ga->verifyCode($secret, $oneCode, 2);    // 2 = 2*30sec clock tolerance
if ($checkResult) {
    echo 'OK';
} else {
    echo 'FAILED';
}
```

I want to know function similar like:
$ga->getauthenticatorusername

Answer (score 0):

Google Authenticator has no notion of a username. You have a secret key; the user sends a token. If the user's token matches your token (generated based on the key and the current time), the user knows the secret key. That's it. If you're asking the user for a username, you need to retrieve it yourself.